# Can someone who doesn't need to file taxes (IRS 1040 etc) get the stimulus check without providing personal information to a 3rd party?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, stimulus

[The IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/non-filers-enter-payment-info-here) sends to [a 3rd party website](https://www.freefilefillableforms.com/#/fd/EconomicImpactPayment).

Is there a different way for someone not filing income tax to provide their information to the IRS? (***Not* necessarily online**.)

<sub>While we're at it, is there a way for someone who *does* need to file a 1040 to do it ***online*** on the IRS site without the need for a 3rd party? (There *should*.)</sub>

Comment: It depends on how you define "3rd party". [Free File](https://www.irs.gov/filing/free-file-do-your-federal-taxes-for-free) Fillable Forms is the only official IRS recommended way of e-filing taxes for free for people with incomes above $69,000. That's pretty official for me. In fact, the [user's guide](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5274.pdf) and [help](https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/free-file-fillable-forms-help) for Free File Fillable Forms are both provided directly by the IRS, not by a company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to send your information via third parties, the only way is to file a tax return using paper forms, which you can download from the IRS web site. Return processing will be slower, so you'll have to wait longer for your stimulus payment. Do enter your direct deposit information on the tax return, even if you don't owe any money, so the IRS will be able to send your stimulus electronically.

I agree, it *should* be possible to file directly on the IRS site, but H&R Block and TurboTax have spent [*millions* to lobby your congressmen and senators](https://www.propublica.org/article/congress-is-about-to-ban-the-government-from-offering-free-online-tax-filing-thank-turbotax).

Comment: "the IRS will not compete with the private sector by providing free on-line tax preparation and filing services to taxpayers" ([federal register, 2002](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/FR-2002-11-04/html/02-27909.htm)) ; written into law [HR 1957 (2019)](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/1957/text#toc-H49976D360AF64F54A7CCB59FA8B440A3), sec 1102(a)(1)